# show line by line in textbox

Tags: c#, forms

I created a C# application with 2 forms..

when i type something on one line in Form 1 it will be displayed with @ letter.

ex. I type $$$$$ in form 1 and it pops up as @$$$$ in Form 2

Form 1

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PassingText = textBox2.Text;
        Form2 A      = new Form2();
        A.Show();

    }
```

Form 2

```
   private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "@" + Form1.PassingText ;


    }
```

but i want to make when i type something with 2 lines it should be pop up as below

I type in form 1

%%%%%%%

&&&&&&&&

form 2 should be

@%%%%%%%

@&&&&&&&&

I have no idea how to do it.Please help me to resolve it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
textBox1.Text = "@"+Form1.PassingText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, Environment.NewLine+"@");
```

Comment: i checked your method is not working. @ will not with all lines